# Is this implementation a fair example of a Promise in PHP?

Tags: php, promise

I've been reading about the Promise pattern, and I tried to code up a version in PHP with the help of a few examples and my own understanding of how it should work. Is what I came up with a reasonable example of the Promise pattern, or did I implement this incorrectly?

```
class PromiseClass {
    private $callbacks = array();
    private $last_return;
    function promise($promise) {
        if (get_class($promise) == 'Promise') {
            return $promise;
        } else if (is_callable($promise)) {
            $this->then($promise);
            return $this;
        }
    }
    public function then (callable $callback) {
        $this->callbacks[] = $callback;
        return $this;
    }
    public function resolve () {
        $callback = array_shift($this->callbacks);
        if (is_callable($callback)) {
            $this->last_return = $callback($this->last_return);
        }
        if (count($this->callbacks) > 0) {
            $this->resolve();
        }
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
$promiser->promise(function() {
        echo "sleeping\n";
        sleep(3);
        return 3;
    })
    ->then(function($args) {
        echo " in second function, $args\n";
    });
$promiser->resolve();
```

Comment: This is better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JohnConde is right. However, to ease your curiosity - this is indeed a Promise pattern in PHP! ... Except that `sleep()` is blocking. Answer incoming.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your Promise implementation is mostly correct. There is, however, a problem: that, at least in PHP, it is mostly useless and almost completely equivalent to the Observer pattern [<sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) [<sup>msdn</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx) [<sup>oodesign</sup>](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html).

PHP is almost completely single-threaded. `sleep` is no exception. As such, your entire Promise will block your script until it is complete. As a result, seeing as the operations are executed inline, you might as well not bother.

A possible way to get rid of that little problem would be to cause your Promise to fork from the main script, which is possible using the PCNTL family of functions. This will allow the Promise code to run in the background, while the main script continues. When the Promise completes, it comes back.

A way to do this is outlined at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php#98711 . It makes active use of `pcntl_fork`, which allows you to fork a new thread. It has drawbacks - the biggest of them being the inability to message the main process by anything but signals.

Comment: Callback hell occurs by sync too if you want to do [cooperative multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking#Cooperative_multitasking). Btw if you have php 5.5 it is better to use [generators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.php) (since 20 Jun 2013) instead of promises... Ohh and ofc you can have threads in php with the [pthreads extension](http://pthreads.org/) (since 2012)... So this answer is "mostly useless"...

Comment: Was searching for this info at https://github.com/reactphp/promise. Nothing said about when script ends. They should add a link to this post on their page

Comment: pcntl now supports context information as well: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/additional-context-in-pcntl-signal-handler

Comment: In this age of web services, making HTTP calls to a different server is a very common use case. And [`curl_multi_init`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) is a feature built into any standard release of PHP that allows for asynchronous HTTP calls. Promises are a rather elegant way to wrap such asynchronous behavior, and this is precisely what popular HTTP libraries for PHP (like Guzzle) are doing. So Promises definitely do have value use cases in PHP even when using just the standard single-threaded version of PHP;

Comment: This question inspired me to implement actual non-block promises in PHP without pcntl_fork or Threads which are usually not available in most shared or managed hosting environments for web requests. I think react-php and other alternatives seem like excessively complex frameworks so I decided to go with my own. Turns out all you are missing to make this useful is an event loop and a way to launch parallel processes which I achieve with shell_exec (which is available in most systems). Here is the gist:
https://gist.github.com/jacmkno/dc13c089c3d641a2c3d48f7cde5c377b